# Is overflow possible in this smart contract?

Tags: solidity, overflow

```
function mint(address beneficiary) public payable {
    uint256 MTCToken = (msg.value/10000) * (10 ** uint256(18));
    uint256 teamToken = (MTCToken/100) * (5);
    balances[owner] += teamToken;
    balances[beneficiary] = balances[beneficiary] + (MTCToken - teamToken);
    totalSupply_ = totalSupply_ + (MTCToken);
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the exact length of the overflow limit. Is it possible to cross the limit in the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to overflow, but we can't say it unless we know what is the type of balances and totalSupply_. It might uint8 and then it would be very easy to overflow balances[owner] or balances[beneficiary] or totalSupply_

If this is uint256 then it still possible, but would require to send a lot of ETH to do it. It doesn't make any sense.

I don't know your requirements so I can't say why you multiplying by 10 ** 18.

```
uint256 MTCToken = (msg.value/10000) * (10 ** uint256(18));
```

msg.value is in Wei so I assume you have a bug here. It is also better first to make multiplication and then division.

> I'm bit confused with the exact length of overflow limit.

**Answer:**
Overflow limit depends from destination variable type. If you are storing results in  uint8 type then maximum value is 255.

So in this example:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

  contract Overflow {
    uint8 iWantToBeCrossed;

    function OverflowMe() public
    {
        iWantToBeCrossed = 100;
        iWantToBeCrossed += 200;

    }

    function ShowMeTheValue () public   view returns (uint8){
        return iWantToBeCrossed;
    }
}
```

Function ShowMeTheValue will return 44 after you call OverflowMe function.

[image]
For uint256 you need bigger values. So theoretically it is possible to overflow, but practically it doesn't make any sense because you would need to send a lot of ETH to your contract.

Answer (score 2):

Overflow is technically possible but not very likely. The highest possible number in a uint256 is (2^256)-1. If someone were to send all the existing ether to that function, MTCToken would still only be 9.7330305e+39, which is only ~133 of the 256 bits.

Note that msg.value is already in wei, so multiplying by 10**18 isn't gonna give you how much wei there is. Also, I would suggest doing multiplication before division, since division will result in dropped decimals. e.g. 12345/100*5 = 615 vs 617.